# use mongoose.populate along with mongoose-pagivate-v2, when data is inside array of object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am getting some data in an array of object like this :

```
 {
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "docs": [
            {
                "_id": "60a602901a74f62935a4898f",
                "user": "607030ba3c82e235443db610",
                "weekNum": 19,
                "__v": 0,
                "createdAt": "2021-05-20T06:32:48.742Z",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "activity": "6063f898232d3f2acca5d2ae",
                        "_id": "60a6063668f27715b0f08753",
                        "project": "60702d1f3c82e235443db5ff",
                        "task": "60702d3d3c82e235443db601",
                        "workingDate": "2021-05-10T18:30:00.000Z",
                        "dayVal": 1,
                        "description": ""
                    }
                ],
                "managersComment": "leleleleelelel",
                "status": "Submitted",
                "updatedAt": "2021-05-20T06:48:22.163Z"
            }
        ],
        "paginator": {
            "itemCount": 1,
            "offset": 0,
            "perPage": 10000,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "currentPage": 1,
            "slNo": 1,
            "hasPrevPage": false,
            "hasNextPage": false,
            "prev": null,
            "next": null
        }
    }
}
```

my schema for this collection in like this:

```
const timesheetSchema = new Schema({
    managersComment: {
        type: String
    },
    weekNum: {
        type: Number
    },
    data:[{
        project: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: projectModel
        },
        task: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: taskModel
        },
        activity: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            default: null,
            ref: activityModel
        },
        workingDate: {
            type: Date
        },
        dayVal: {
            type: Number
        },
        description: {
            type: String
        },
    }],    
    user: { type: ObjectId, ref: userModel },    
    status: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Saved', 'Submitted', 'Approved', 'Rejected', 'Reset']
    },
    
}, { timestamps: true });
timesheetSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
const timesheetModel = mongoose.model('timesheet', timesheetSchema);
```

my code for getting data is something like this:

```
try {
    console.log('populateRequired --------------------------------------------------')
    const populateArray = [
        { path: "task", select: "taskName" },
        { path: "project", select: "projectName" },
        { path: "activity", select: "title" },
    ];
    const query = {
        user: req.params.userId,
        status: req.query.status,
    };
    const paginationParams = {
        populate: populateArray,
        customLabels: customLabels,
        limit: req.query.limit,
    };
    console.log("USER QUERY    ", query);
    const userTimesheet = await getTimesheetDataByUserId(
        query,
        paginationParams
    );
    console.log(userTimesheet);
    res.send({ success: true, result: userTimesheet });
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    next(err);
}
```

But as shown in return data above i am not getting populate applied in `data array`. Please help not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

According to the data you posted, I think that the issue is that you're not creating virtual fields to populate with your references. Your fields project, task and activity in each array element, or user, are meant to be ids referring to the corresponding models. But those ids alone will not implement the population, they are only the pointers that the population will need in order to be executed. To make that a little bit more clear, I would change those names to `userId: { type: ObjectId, ref: userModel }`.
After that, you will need to create the virtual fields:

```
timesheetSchema.virtual("user", {
  ref: "userModel",
  localField: "userId",
  foreignField: "_id",
  justOne: true,
});
```

Finally, if you want to have the virtual field timesheet.user populated each time you query your collection, you will have to add some middleware to your schema. For me, the most reasonable way to make this work is:

```
timesheetSchema.pre("find", function (next) {
  this.populate("user");

  next();
});
```

Just to have a complete solution: I think this will solve your problem for the timesheet.user field. But I don't think it will work in your data array. In fact, I'm not 100% sure the way you're defining it is really going to work: creating a timesheet with an array of imputations doesn't make too much sense to me. A more coherent approach would be creating a collection of all the imputations that looked like this:

```
const dataSchema = new Schema({
    projectId: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: projectModel
    },
    taskId: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: taskModel
    },
    activityId: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        default: null,
        ref: activityModel
    },
    userId: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: userModel
    },
    workingDate: {
        type: Date
    },
    dayVal: {
        type: Number
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
});
```

With virtual fields like:

```
dataSchema.virtual("project", {
    ref: projectModel,
    localField: "projectId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    justOne: true
});
```

And so on. I would populate each field just like I showed you with the user example. Then, for the timesheet schema I would only reference userId, and populate data like this:

```
const timesheetSchema = new Schema({
    managersComment: {
        type: String
    },
    weekNum: {
        type: Number
    },  
    userId: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: dataModel 
    },    
    status: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Saved', 'Submitted', 'Approved', 'Rejected', 'Reset']
    },
    
}, { timestamps: true });

timesheetSchema.virtual("data", {
    ref: dataModel,
    localField: "userId",
    foreignField: "userId"
});

timesheetSchema.virtual("user", {
    ref: userModel,
    localField: "userId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    justOne: true
});
```

This way you would have a collection with all the imputations for all the users, and you would be able to query and filter that collection for each userId, projectId or anything you would need. Having an array inside your timesheet collection would make this quite more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution I found on another SO post is like this:

```
const result = await timesheetModel.findOne(query).populate({
     path: 'data.project data.activity data.task'
});
```